# Two RelativeLayouts sharing screen width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two `RelativeLayouts`. Each of them has some content which is unknown width. I cant use `LinearLayout` and set `layout_weight`, because one of this `RelativeLayout` has `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and I don't know if it will be enough for children in terms of width.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:background="@color/grey">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/secondLayout">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give some specific width to the second layout instead of `wrap_content` like this I have given 100dp here

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:background="@color/grey">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/secondLayout">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cant, because child of this second layout can have dynamic width. Its TextView which can be longer than 100dp

Comment: Can't you make it multiline ... i.e the text can wrap itself to multiline...

Comment: Nope, it has to be single line

Comment: Then how about first layout is it also going to be dynamic width ?

Comment: I solved it by adding first layout to fixed width and then used marque for TextView if it doesnt fit.

Comment: Yeah ... either way, you were supposed to compromise on the width of at least one layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make layout what you expect, there are many way.

for example, (only use LinearLayout and RelativeLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/secondLayout"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="header"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this xml can make this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#858585"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#66b35f"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/secondLayout"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#6e89c2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

You should use the parameter "android:minWidth="Xdp"
Then it looks like above.

Comment: This is not working. First layout disappeared and second one stretched to entire width